# Dart Packages folder not existing anymore how do I integrate with symfony now for development

Tags: symfony, dart

Back in the times of dart 1.9.x I made a dart frontend with symfony rest backend. Today I wanted to setup a development environment to do some more work on that app.

Unfortunately it turned out that dart 1.21.x does no longer create a packages folder where all the dart files are. This not only breaks the way integration worked up until now for development but it also breaks how template Urls are resolved by anything other than pub serve

Appart from creating the packages folder symlinks myself or completely rewriting the App. Does anybody know a good way to integrate the latest dart with Symfony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can opt-in

```
pub get --packages-dir
```

but the option is planned to be removed eventually, therefore try to find a way your application works without it.
The migration to code generation, DDC, and bazel might make this easier (none  released yet)

There are also the packages

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/package_resolver
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/package_config

that help with the `.packages` file that replaces the `packages` directory and symlinks.

The [sass](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sass) package (which most often causes issues with the missing `packages` directory) also should become available in a version that doesn't depend on the `packages` directory soon.